# Compile error in SFML 2.5.1 sample code in Linux

Tags: c++, sfml

[Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E6zw.jpg)

I was looking at a configuration video in yt for linux mint but it doesn't give me the same results in arch.

```
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question. It appears you have some syntax errors.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or error messages. Put all relevant information in the question as *text*.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can mention the version of SFML library you are using.

Comment: You're saying that your school work requires you to learn SFML, but your instructor provides no guidance, no information, and no resources, whatsoever, that are needed to accomplish the assigned work? Sounds like you need to switch classes to a more competent instructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicate, there is no constructor for `sf::VideoMode` which takes two `int` input for width and height. The constructor expect an argument of type `Vector2u`.

Create the Window as follows:

```cpp
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({200, 200}), "SFML works!");
```